# how to refresh a page every time when i back here?

Tags: flutter, dart

i add a list view with add button.
when i click the button it pushes me to another screen. and i can add another list.
but when i return there, this page is not refreshed automatically.
i need to refresh this page every time when i come from any where

this is add button

```
FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    onPressed: () {
      Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => addPlan());
      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(new MaterialPageRoute<String>(maintainState: true))
          .then((String value) {
        print(value);
      });
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
```

and this is my when i add a new list this button

```
 RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.black,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            onPressed: () {
              clickadd();
            },
            child: Text(
              'Add Plan',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: Have you tried `setState()`...?

Comment: what i put in setState.

and this list is from Json API..

i just need this page refresh everytime when i back here from anywhere.

Comment: Why are you doing Json API fetch in `build`? Initiate your list in `initState` and use it in `build`. So it won't fetch everytime. If you want to re-fetch then use combination of setState and Json API fetch.

Comment: brother its work thank you.
but i already add this on initState but now when i set this on initstate this is work well  thanks :)